# Add multiples file into a zip file using c#

Tags: c#, zip, .net-assembly, archive

I want to add multiple files into a zip files but when I run my code. I got a error. I got 2 errors in **Archive()** and **ArchiveSaveOptions()** methods.

Error   **CS0246    The type or namespace name 'Archive' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?** ConvertMultipleFilesIntoZip
C:\Users\sanjeev_kushvaha\source\repos\ConvertMultipleFilesIntoZip\ConvertMultipleFilesIntoZip\Program.cs

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

namespace ConvertMultipleFilesIntoZip
{
    internal class Program
    {   
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            
            using (FileStream zipFile = File.Open("compressed_files.zip", FileMode.Create))
            {
                // File to be added to archive
                using (FileStream source1 = File.Open("alice29.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                {
                    // File to be added to archive
                    using (FileStream source2 = File.Open("asyoulike.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                    {
                        using (var archive = new Archive())
                        {
                            // Add files to the archive
                            archive.CreateEntry("alice29.txt", source1);
                            archive.CreateEntry("asyoulik3.txt", source2);
                            // ZIP the files
                            archive.Save(zipFile, new ArchiveSaveOptions() { Encoding = Encoding.ASCII, ArchiveComment = "two files are compressed in this archive" });
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }

        
    }
}
```

Comment: I got error in Archive() and ArchiveSaveOptions().

Comment: Looks like you didn't include correct namespace

Comment: You seem to be using a 3rd party library (maybe Aspose.zip?). Did you add the required nuget packages or assembly references to your project? You probably also need to add some `using` directives.

Comment: I am not missing any namespace.

Comment: @KlausGütter I added required assembles and packages.

Comment: @Deleted I want only solution of that error. And what I doing, I explain in title.

Comment: Then you still need to add the correct `using` directives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use [ZipArchive Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.ziparchive?view=net-7.0) to create zip file include `asyoulik3.txt` and `alice29.txt` :

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.IO.Compression;

namespace ConvertMultipleFilesIntoZip
{
    internal class Program
    {   
        static void Main(string[] args)
       {
            using (ZipArchive archive = ZipFile.Open("compressed_files.zip", ZipArchiveMode.Create))
            {

                archive.CreateEntryFromFile("asyoulik3.txt", "asyoulik3.txt");
                archive.CreateEntryFromFile("alice29.txt", "alice29.txt");
            }
        }
    }
}
```